# Cant seem to get this role to be created discord js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I looked on the docs this is what i shows so i just edited it some to make it what i want the role to have created with the permissions then from thier i tried the command and got a error. i tried several ways still cant get it to work this is my first time trying this so i could see why its not working

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: 'muterolecreate',
    usage: '%muterolecreate',
    discription: "makes a muterole",
    execute(client, message, args) {

        guild.roles.create({
            data: {
              name: 'muted',
              color: 'RED',
              permissions: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNELS"]
            },
          })
          message.channel.send(`${role} created`)
    }
}
```

error

```js
PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot> node .
Cbs slave is online!
C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\moderationcommands\muterolecreate.js:9
        guild.roles.create({
        ^

ReferenceError: guild is not defined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\moderationcommands\muterolecreate.js:9:9)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\events\guild\message.js:10:26)
    at Client.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:834:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:437:14)
    at Receiver.getData (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:367:17)
    at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:143:22)
    at Receiver._write (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:78:10)
PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at what your error says instead of defaulting to confusion.  `guild` isn't defined, so you need to do so.

If you want a specific guild, use `<client>.guilds.cache.get('guildIDHere')`.

If you want the guild that the command was sent from, use `message.guild`.

Comment: alright how wuld i  do it with any guild not just one?

Comment: @cb12438 You were given the solution to this same issue in your previous post. You keep trying to use variables that have never been defined. As another example you try to log `role` without defining it. I highly suggest you [Check This Out](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript) before continuing any further with Discord.JS

Answer (score 0):

So basically you just need to define the guild.

Use `<client>.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID")`

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: 'muterolecreate',
    usage: '%muterolecreate',
    discription: "makes a muterole",
    execute(client, message, args) {
    
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID")
        
        guild.roles.create({
            data: {
              name: 'muted',
              color: 'RED',
              permissions: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "VIEW_CHANNELS"]
            },
          })
          message.channel.send(`${role} created`)
    }
}
```